# Pointer object getting corrupted somewhere

Tags: c++, pointers, vector

I have two classes, Curve and ChildCurve. ChildCurve inherits from Curve.

Curve has the following private field

```
vector<Point2*>* curvePoints;
```

and the following public method

```
vector<Point2*>* getCurvePoints();
```

ChildCurve has a method that modifies this field as follows.

```
vector<Point2*> *pts = this->getCurvePoints();
pts->clear();
Point2 q1 = Point2(1.0, 3.0); 
Point2 q2 = Point2(2.0, 4.0); 
pts->push_back(&q1); 
pts->push_back(&q2);
cout << qvec->at(0)->getX() << ", " <<  qvec->at(0)->getY()  << endl;
```

At this point, the correct values are printed.

Later, from some other class, I try to retrieve the points I stored in the vector.

```
vector<Point2*> *curvePoints = curve->getCurvePoints();
for(int i = 0; i < curvePoints->size(); i++){
    Point2* p = curvePoints->at(i);
    cout << p->getX() << ", " << p->getY() << endl;
}
```

But all the points have garbage coordinates close to 0, like

```
2.22507e-308, 6.91993e-310
```

I'm pretty sure there is nothing touching that vector aside from what I described here. What could be wrong? Where could this values be getting corrupted?

Comment: It looks like you are filling a vector of pointers with pointers to objects that have a shorter lifetime (`q1` and `q2` foe example), leaving it full of dangling pointers.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is the culprit:

```
Point2 q1 = Point2(1.0, 3.0); 
Point2 q2 = Point2(2.0, 4.0); 
pts->push_back(&q1); 
pts->push_back(&q2);
```

You push pointers to objects local to a function into a vector that survives past the end of the function. While the function is running, the locals are valid, so you can print them OK. Once the function is over, though, the locals become invalid. Trying to dereference pointers to them in undefined behavior.

You can fix this simply by pushing `new Point2` into the vector, like this:

```
pts->push_back(new Point2(1.0, 3.0)); 
pts->push_back(new Point2(2.0, 4.0));
```

Of course you will have to delete these objects as well.

A better approach is to use a vector of `Point2`s, not `Point2*`s. If you must use pointers for polymorphic behavior, use `std::unique_ptr` instead of raw pointers to simplify your memory management.

Answer (score 1):

You stored pointers to objects with local storage (`q1` and `q2`).

When your method ends, these objects cease to exist and pointers to them become invalid.

Never do that.

Answer (score 1):

```
Point2 q1 = Point2(1.0, 3.0); 
Point2 q2 = Point2(2.0, 4.0); 
pts->push_back(&q1); 
pts->push_back(&q2);
```

You are storing pointers to stack variables, that gets destroyed at the end of scope. Meaning when you access them again, you invoke an undefined behavior.

Answer (score 1):

Please avoid pointers:

Your points q1 and q2  passed as pointers run out of scope and become garbage.

Answer (score 1):

q1 and q2 are local variables, which are destroyed after the method returns. So pointer to them points to garbage later.